# How to get rid of "shadow teeth" in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, shadow

I tried everything but nothing can affect this. The only thing is when I change shadow resolution to "low", it becomes more smooth (obviously), but still not the best. Those shadows also look better if angle of view is less acute. Quality settings are the best, light source is a spotlight. Material on those things uses standard shader. What do I do wrong?

Image is enlarged.

[image: Shadow teeth]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You...can't. :(

The problem is that the shadows being cast are essentially just a texture. And texture points (aka "pixels") are square. This shadow texture is then "cast" from the light source (think about the light as being a camera: every pixel that it can see that is an object, that becomes a "dark" pixel in the lightmap; its a bit more complicated than that, but not by much).

Your objects and light are *definitely* not square up from each other. And in fact, can *never* be as your cubes are rotated five to ten degrees from each other forming a curve.  Which means that some edge, somewhere, is going to get jaggy.  This also explains why changing the light's position and orientation to a different angle affects the result: those edges more closely (or less closely) align with where the lightmap pixels are.

You can try various settings, such as Stable Fit or higher quality shadows (this is really just "use a bigger texture" so those jaggies get smaller as the same volume is covered by more shadow-pixels) but fundamentally you're not going to get a better result.

## Unless...

You use baked lighting.  Open up the Lighting window (Window -> Lighting), set your lights as baked rather than forward/deferred (this means they will **not be realtime** and may not move or otherwise change) and then in the Lighting window, bake your lights.

This essentially creates a second texture that is wrapped around your objects and gives them shadows and the pixels line up differently and generally give smoother shadow edges when the object's faces align with the shadow-casting edge (such as your stacked cubes).  The textures are also *much larger* than the runtime light textures because it doesn't have to be recomputed every frame (realtime lights are restricted so they don't consume gigabytes of video RAM).

Baking will take a while, let it do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with Stable Fit (under Quality settings)?

Comment: Sorry, I mean Stable Fit. Anyway, have you tested applying antialias?